# throwing an error while trying to convert the data types in mongoshell

Tags: database, mongodb, pymongo, mongo-shell

I created a database named as database and a collection called Netflix. there is a field in the database called `"genres"` which was of type string I need to change the data type to the array. I am trying to use the below command in the mongo shell but it's throwing an error.

```js
db.netflix.find({}).forEach(function(x){x.genres=JSON.parse(x.genres); db.netflix.save(x); })
```

```
**Error:**
TypeError: db.netflix.save is not a function
```

below pic shows how the data in genres field looks like

[image: below pic shows how the data in genres field looks like]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to let the MongoDB server do all the work by using a pipeline in an `update`.

N.B.:  I have little regex-foo so there is a better regex. E.g., if an element of `"genres"` (between quotes) contains a comma, the `"regex"` below won't be sufficient.  Also note that I needed to escape `"` with `\` in the `"regex"` - you may, or may not need to do this.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "genres": {
    "$type": "string"
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "genres": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$regexFindAll": {
              "input": "$genres",
              "regex": "(?<=\")[^,]*?(?=\")"
            }
          },
          "as": "elem",
          "in": "$$elem.match"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HoQQYWGHwlu). (Modified [sample document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/sample-data/sample-mflix/#sample-document-1) from MongoDB Atlas documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Starting in MongoDB 4.2, the
db.collection.save()
method is deprecated. Use
db.collection.insertOne()
or
db.collection.replaceOne()
instead.

for the above query , you can try, this works:

db.netflix.find({}).forEach(function(x){x.genres= JSON.parse(x.genres); db.netflix.replaceOne({id:x.id},x); });